# User management and security module for a java application over Spring

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security, user-management

I need to design a web service API for a java application.
I figured spring + tomcat would be the best choice, as it's very widely used.
The security aspect of the web service is of very high importance.

After doing some research and reading some tutorials (about spring-security and all of its derivatives), I managed to get the service up and running, with a very standard authentication method (usernames and hashed passwords in a DB table).

My colleague who has done pretty much the same task in grails has shown me how he managed to do the same things and then some more important features like locking accounts, limiting max attempts per user, user management console with significantly smaller amount boilerplate code, using some plugins from the "Spring Security Core Plugin" family.

Now, I could write all of these things myself, but I don't think I should because:
1. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.
2. I'll probably miss out on some important security related things (which is bad, because security is very important here).
3. It seems very peculiar to me that such solutions exist for grails and not for java.

So, is there any good out of the box solution for java + spring + tomcat?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you classify as good. There is a [Spring Security UI Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/v3/index.html) that does some authentication/authorization functionality.

Comment: If you dont want to use Grails check Spring Boot, but I'm not sure why you don't want to use Grails if this is already working and requires not much code

Comment: @droggo There's a big codebase written in java whoch cannot be conveniently wrapped in a jar and supplied as a service to a grails module

Comment: @Aramiti You referred me to the grails plugin. I need a java based solution...

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague already answered that for you: Spring Security is, after all, java based and the grails plugin is building on that.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/